# Várias sessões simultâneas no ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

estou tendo um probleminha para ter multiplus usuários simultâneo em uma app web ASP.net com C#. Quando logo com outro usuário a sessão anterior é derrubada.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?Como faço para ter todas as sessões autenticadas e ativas independentes uma da outra.

Comment: Se não me engano quando vc usa abas diferentes ele por padrão tende a fazer isso mesmo, agora se você abrir uma nova janela ele mantem as sessões.

Comment: Com abas diferente ele realmente faz isso, mas com browser não, ele abre uma nova sessão para cada navegador, e o que esta acontecendo é que ele esta pegando a sessão do outro navegador.